# Which platform do I need to select in Google Fit API for the flutter app development?

Tags: google-api, dart, flutter, google-fit-sdk

Which platform do I need to select if I am trying to build an Recording step counter for Android and iOS with the help of flutter?

**Where will you be calling the API from?** 
[image]

Comment: I'd say "Other UI"